# Cordova - Displaying local image files in a <img> tag

Tags: ios, cordova, ember.js

I have a Cordova app (built on Ember.js, using the Corber addon) that I am currently only running on iOS, specifically the iOS simulator (iPhone 8, iOS v12), so it is using a `WKWEBVIEW`.

The app is using cordova's file plugins to download remote images and store them on the user's device, currently in the "Documents" (`cordova.file.documentsDirectory`), which works fine, and I've verified that the images do in fact exist there. However I can't figure out the correct URL/URI to use to display those images in the app via standard `<img>` tags.

Cordova's own documentation says to use the `cdvfile://` protocol path (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#cdvfile-protocol), but even with following the instructions there (adding the content-security meta tag to the index.html, the access rule to the config.xml, etc), it seems like WKWEBVIEW just flat out does not support this protocol, giving me "unsupported URL" errors in the console when I attempt to use it.

Other SO answers on the subject suggest using a normal URL path relative to the cordova app's web server URL, e.g. things like `<img src="/Library/NoCloud/path-to-my/file.jpg">` but any path I try 404's.

This seems like such a simple/common use case, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Isn't it possible through base64(readAsDataURL)?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else struggling as I was - there is also a solution, which requires no significant change to the code which I found after hopeless days when no solution seemed available

There are 2 steps required:

First update your config.xml with following

```
<platform name="ios">    
  <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
  <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
 </platform>
```

Then convert your file:// link by using the undocumented method

```
window.WkWebView.convertFilePath(filePath)
```

This method performs the conversion into a virtual localhost link that makes the file accessible and bypasses the WkWebView restrictions. A little bit longer sample goes like this

```
let localFile = cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'logo.png';
let convertedPath = window.WkWebView.convertFilePath(localFile);
document.getElementById("myImg").src = convertedPath;
```

Comment: What is window here? How do we get window.WKWebView.convertFilePath() method?

Answer (score 0):

I did not work with Cordova but docs you linked say this:

> To use cdvfile as a tag' src you can convert it to native path via toURL() method of the resolved fileEntry, which you can get via resolveLocalFileSystemURL - see examples below.

And gives this as an example:

```
resolveLocalFileSystemURL('cdvfile://localhost/temporary/path/to/file.mp4', function(entry) {
    var nativePath = entry.toURL();
    console.log('Native URI: ' + nativePath);
    document.getElementById('video').src = nativePath;
```

Given all that, I would say that you can try to create a component, `cdv-img`. Something like this supposed to work, I think:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  tagName: 'img',
  cdvPath: undefined,
  didReceiveAttrs() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    if (this.cdvPath) {
      resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.cdvPath, (entry) => {
        this.$().attr('src', entry.toURL());
      });
    }
  },
});
```

Use it like this:

```
{{cdv-img cdvPath='cdvfile://localhost/temporary/path/to/file.jpg'}}
```

### UPD

If it does not work with file protocol, you can try to convert image to data url

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  tagName: 'img',
  cdvPath: undefined,
  didReceiveAttrs() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    if (this.cdvPath) {
      const el = this.$();
      resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.cdvPath, (entry) => {
        entry.file(function (file) {
          const reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onloadend = function() {
            el.attr('src', this.result);
          };

          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
      });
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I initially had something similar to this, attempting to just use the native path returned by `toUrl()`, but the problem is that returns a URI in the form of `file:///path/to/file.jpg`, and that didnt work in iOS simulator, I was getting content security errors that "local file urls are not allowed".

Comment: @BillDami you can try to convert to data url (see updated answer)

Comment: Thanks, yeah I had seen other answers suggest that as well, unfortunately I cannot take on the additional processing overhead that  converting to data urls would incur, as the app is rendering 100s of these images, in a very quick manner.

Comment: @BillDami did you measure overhead? It might be acceptable. But if no, then I have no further ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't forget to add these 2 lines and try with whatever solution you are trying, I got my images shown after adding them:

In your config.xml file. add:

```
<preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
<preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
```